# How to scroll in Ext.Container

Tags: sencha-touch

Below is my view. how can I make my menu scroll separate and my view scroll separate

```
Ext.define('HaBoMobile.view.AboutView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'aboutViewType',
    html: 'Learn more about me',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable : {
        direction     : 'vertical',
        directionLock : true
    },
    overflowY: 'auto',
    autoScroll: true,
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            items: [{
                text: 'Menu',
                action: 'nav',
                iconCls: 'list'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

I tried all these settings, none worked
   **scrollable : {
            direction     : 'vertical',
            directionLock : true
        },
        overflowY: 'auto',
        autoScroll: true,**

here is a [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/f8e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with `scrollable: true`, like this:-

```
 var menu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
             scrollable: true,  // add this property
            width: 200,  // Need to set a width 
            items: [{
                text: 'Close',
                ui: 'decline'
            }, {
                text: 'Home',
                action: 'nav_option',
                iconCls: 'home'
            }, {
                text: 'Settings',
                action: 'nav_option',
                iconCls: 'settings'
            }]
        });
```

Containers:-

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainview',
    config: {            
        scrollable: true,
         html: 'Main page',
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Main',
            items: [{
                text: 'Nav',
                action: 'nav'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```